# How to append a node in the existing JSON string?

Tags: c#

I have a JSON String as below.

```
 {
 "Filename":"mypage.html",
 "Info":{
  "title":{
     "Name":"title",
     "Values":[
        "This is title"
     ],
     "NumericValues":[

     ],
     "DateTimeValues":[

     ],
     "LinkedComponentValues":[

     ],
     "FieldType":0
  }
   },
  "Id":"123",
   "Title":"This is my page"
  }
```

I am desearilizing the JSON input string as below.

```
 var outputobject= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(input);
```

Now I would like to add a below new node in the input JSON string (**after the title in the info**) using C#.

```
"description":{
     "Name":"description",
     "Values":[
        "This is description"
     ],
     "NumericValues":[

     ],
     "DateTimeValues":[

     ],
     "LinkedComponentValues":[

     ],
     "FieldType":0
  }
```

After adding the node, I want to searilize the object into string.
I am facing issue to add the new node in the input json string under the Info node. I am just giving small example. But my input JSON string is big one and it has different structure. but it is valid JSON.

**My Final JSON should be as below.**

```
       {
    "Filename":"mypage.html",
   "Info":{
  "title":{
     "Name":"title",
     "Values":[
        "This is title"
     ],
     "NumericValues":[

     ],
     "DateTimeValues":[

     ],
     "LinkedComponentValues":[

     ],
     "FieldType":0
  }

      "description":{
     "Name":"description",
     "Values":[
        "This is description"
     ],
     "NumericValues":[

     ],
     "DateTimeValues":[

     ],
     "LinkedComponentValues":[

     ],
     "FieldType":0
  }

   },



  "Id":"123",
   "Title":"This is my page"
  }
```

This is what am trying, I need to add inside the "Info". Please note, am not creating a model or generating input JSON. I am getting an input JSON as string. After getting JSON string, I need to append a attribute (Description) inside the "Info".

```
 var inputobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(input);
        var description = new Description
        {
            Name = "Description",
            Values = new List<string>{"This is description"},
            NumericValues = new List<string>(),
            DateTimeValues = new List<string>(),
            LinkedComponentValues = new List<string>(),
            FieldType = 0,
            KeywordValues = new List<string>(),

        };

        var descriptionObject = JObject.FromObject(description);
        var test = JObject.FromObject(inputobject);
        test.Add("Descrition", descriptionObject);
```

Regards,
Jey

Comment: Why does it matter if it is after the `Title` property? You're just making an object. The order of the properties (not "nodes") doesn't matter at all.

Comment: I agree.. order does not matter when it comes to an object.

Comment: Can you add the final json that you want, to your question?

Comment: @Kosala, I have added the final output needed.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Json.Net's index[]](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ModifyJson.htm) to modify JSON.

[image]

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var item = @"
            {
                ""Filename"":""mypage.html"",
                ""Info"":{
                    ""title"":{
                        ""Name"":""title"",
                        ""Values"":[""This is title""],
                        ""NumericValues"":[],
                        ""DateTimeValues"":[],
                        ""LinkedComponentValues"":[],
                        ""FieldType"":0
                    }
                },
                ""Id"":""123"",
                ""Title"":""This is my page""
            }";

        var description = @"{
                ""Name"":""description"",
                ""Values"":[""This is description""],
                ""NumericValues"":[],
                ""DateTimeValues"":[],
                ""LinkedComponentValues"":[],
                ""FieldType"":0}";

        var itemJObj = JObject.Parse(item);
        var descriptionJObj = JObject.Parse(description);

        var titleJObj = itemJObj["Info"] as JObject;
        titleJObj.Add("description", descriptionJObj);

        var serializer = new JsonSerializer{ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()};
        var json = JObject.FromObject(itemJObj, serializer);

        Console.WriteLine(json);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Win, I need to add inside the "Info". I am able to add in the object as you did and that comes as last which is not an issue. More over, under info, I will get more attributes than I specified, I don't know the list of attributes and its names. so I could not able to create a model defined.

Comment: After desearilizing the JSON input, somehow I need to identify the "Info" and add the another set of attribute inside the "Info". I can create the description object using JObject. the issue am facing is, how to insert the description object inside the "Info"?

Comment: Without seeing your code I could not tell. It could be same has what I did in my question.

Comment: you are creating a description object and adding that in the itemobject, which is adding at the end of the JSON. I am able to do that. My issue is not sure how to add my description object inside the "Info" not in the itemobject (which means, not the end of the JSON)

Answer (score 0):

Always make sure your viewmodels represent what you want to get as the final output.

First Change your classes like below.

```
public class JsonRoot
{
    public string Filename { get; set; }

    public Info Info { get; set; }

    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class Info
{
    public Title title { get; set; }

    public Description description { get; set; }
}

public class Title
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string[] Values { get; set; }

    public object[] NumericValues { get; set; }

    public object[] DateTimeValues { get; set; }

    public object[] LinkedComponentValues { get; set; }

    public int FieldType { get; set; }
}

public class Description
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string[] Values { get; set; }

    public object[] NumericValues { get; set; }

    public object[] DateTimeValues { get; set; }

    public object[] LinkedComponentValues { get; set; }

    public int FieldType { get; set; }
}
```

Then test your json using this test class.

```
public class MyJsonTest
{
    public void TestNewJson()
    {
        var root = new JsonRoot()
        {
            Filename = "mypage.html",
            Id = "123",
            Title = "This is my page",
            Info = new Info()
                    {
                        description =
                            new Description()
                            {
                                DateTimeValues = new object[] { DateTime.Now, DateTime.UtcNow },
                                FieldType = 1,
                                LinkedComponentValues = new object[] { "ABC", "XYZ" },
                                Name = "MyInfo",
                                NumericValues = new object[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
                                Values = (new List<string> { "some values" }).ToArray(),
                            },
                        title = new Title()
                            {
                                FieldType = 5,
                                NumericValues = new object[] { 1, 2, 43 },
                                Values = new string[] { "sdfs", "dfgdf" },
                                Name = "Some name",
                                LinkedComponentValues = new object[] {"34555", "678786"},
                                DateTimeValues = new object[] {DateTime.Now},
                            },
                    },
        };

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
```

This should give you a json like below.

```
{
  "Filename": "mypage.html",
  "Info": {
    "title": {
      "Name": "Some name",
      "Values": [
        "sdfs",
        "dfgdf"
      ],
      "NumericValues": [
        1,
        2,
        43
      ],
      "DateTimeValues": [
        "2016-09-28T09:57:52.1513109+10:00"
      ],
      "LinkedComponentValues": [
        "34555",
        "678786"
      ],
      "FieldType": 5
    },
    "description": {
      "Name": "MyInfo",
      "Values": [
        "some values"
      ],
      "NumericValues": [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5
      ],
      "DateTimeValues": [
        "2016-09-28T09:57:52.1498114+10:00",
        "2016-09-27T23:57:52.1508118Z"
      ],
      "LinkedComponentValues": [
        "ABC",
        "XYZ"
      ],
      "FieldType": 1
    }
  },
  "Id": "123",
  "Title": "This is my page"
}
```

Comment: I need to add inside the "Info". Please note, am not creating a model or generating input JSON. I am getting an input JSON as string. After getting JSON string, I need to append a attribute (Description) inside the "Info".

Comment: Did you say you need to add "description" inside the "info"? I understand  you are not generating an input json, but trying to create an output json. That's what I am trying to help you with. As you may be aware, json is not just a "string". It is a string representation of an object. So solving a problem in your "string" will not solve the underling problem.